# Why is grep -o -w not giving me the expected output on Mac OS X?

Tags: bash, grep

If I do `echo foo bar baz | grep -o -w baz` the output is `foo bar baz` (and an extra newline).
The expected output would be `baz` as the -o option should only display the matched part.
I'm using Mac OS X 10.7.1 and the grep version is `grep (GNU grep) 2.5.1`

Comment: Hmm. Works correctly with `grep (GNU grep) 2.9` (Gentoo)

Comment: Works for me too with GNU grep 2.5.3 on Linux.  On OS X 10.5.8 (GNU grep 2.5.1) I can confirm that it does not work.

Comment: I can't reproduce this with a grep 2.5.1 compiled from source. Do you have any `GREP_*` environment variable set?

Comment: @Gilles No I don't

Comment: Confirmed issue on Mac OS X Lion - just ran into it myself :-/  Frank's solution works for me.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There's a workaround by using the `grep` regex syntax for matching the empty string at the beginning and end of a word!

```
# grep regex syntax for matching words only
man grep | less -p '\<'

# POSIX 1003.2 regular expression syntax for matching words only
# should work for sed, ed, ...
man re_format | less -p '\[\[:<:\]\]'

echo 'foo bar baz' | egrep -o '\<baz\>'

echo 'foo bar baz' | sed -n '/.*[[:<:]]\(baz\)[[:>:]].*/s//\1/p'
```

If you insist on using `grep`'s `-w` flag, try the precompiled Rudix 2010 `grep` binary (grep-2.5.4-1.dmg).

http://rudix.org/packages-ghi.html#grep

Answer (score 0):

Seems like a bug to me. If you don't mind using the `grep` from macports (v 2.9), it behaves the way you expect.

2.5.1 seems is far from the latest release, but I suppose you could try filling a bug with Apple.

Comment: Before reporting a bug to GNU, you should check whether more recent versions and home-compiled binaries have the same issue. I doubt GNU would appreciate a bug report if the problem turned out to be the way Apple built the binary, or if the issue has been fixed a long time ago.

Answer (score 0):

Alternatively, you could install a newer version of GNU `grep` via [Homebrew](https://brew.sh):

```
brew install grep
```

Then do the following:

```
$ echo foo bar baz | ggrep -o -w baz
baz
```

Answer (score 0):

In 10.8, `/usr/bin/grep` was replaced with a different version of grep, which doesn't seem to have that issue:

```
$ echo foo bar baz | grep -o -w baz
baz
$ grep -V
grep (BSD grep) 2.5.1-FreeBSD
```

10.7:

```
$ echo foo bar baz | grep -o -w baz
foo bar baz

$ grep -V
grep (GNU grep) 2.5.1

Copyright 1988, 1992-1999, 2000, 2001 Free Software Foundation, Inc.
This is free software; see the source for copying conditions. There is NO
warranty; not even for MERCHANTABILITY or FITNESS FOR A PARTICULAR PURPOSE.
```